# Video information in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, video, mediaelement

How can I read information (the summary) from a video file I am playing in mediaelement like name, poster, album etc. like media player do.

Or even read a file properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write your own parser for the file type.  If it's a WMV file, you would have to parse the file's header.  The ASF spec is located here:  http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/format/asfspec.aspx